# My Subversion keeps excluding my files

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn

Every time I checkout my site from my repository. I notice most of my files that I have are excluded. So I have to go hunt down every file and include it in the project. This is very annoying.

I am using Subversion and tortiseSVN for windows.

What do I need to do to stop this?

Comment: Not enough information. What does "most of my files" mean? Are they files of a specific type or extension? Are they text or binary? Did you add them to your repository correctly? Where is your repository physically located? (If it's under the %PROGRAMFILES% folder and you're not an administrator, the folder is virtualized under Vista and above; this can happen in other folders as well.)

Comment: Have you add those files to the repository (and committed those adds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand correctly, but after you have added the files to your project, did you commit the project file?

If not, the files will still be excluded when you checkout the project the next time.

Comment: This could be. I usually do not include it since there are some changes in it to add nunit to VisualStudios and each computer has a different path. I was not aware that it controlled these things. The weird thing though is that I have other solution files(in the same project) where I do commit the project file and I still get this problem. But I just uploaded the project file for the one I normally do not commit and it solved the problem. So not sure why it solves one problem but not the rest.

Comment: I am also having problems with references. It sometimes does not add all the system dll references I have. So got to compare them against computers to make sure all are found.

Comment: After making changes to the project file, make sure that you save everything in Visual Studio before you commit the files (e.g. by compiling the solution).

Comment: @chobo2 - What kind of project is this?  Does it happen to be a Web Site project?

Comment: @The Lame Duck - This is an asp.net mvc website.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your "Global ignore patterns" in the settings section?

Use the right click menu to get to settings:

[alt text http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/2452/rightclicksvn.png](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/2452/rightclicksvn.png)

You'll see the "Global Ignore Patterns" field in the middle and it will have a long list of ignored file types.  Copy and past it into notepad and see if your problem file types are in this list.

[alt text http://img176.imageshack.us/img176/2521/globalignorepattern.png](http://img176.imageshack.us/img176/2521/globalignorepattern.png)

**Alternatively**

The other meaning I take from your question could be that when you checkout the code and a new file has been added by someone else, the file appears on your local drive, but not in Visual Studio.

In that case, you probably don't have your project file under source control.  It contains the master list of which files should be contain in a project and if it isn't kept in source control, then when another developer adds new files, they will be copied to other team members' machines, but they won't be added to the VS project.